# How to put zombie dwarf in a cage?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

An evil cloud had approached my fortress, and I think one of my dwarves got caught in it because he's now a zombie.

He eventually triggered one of my cage traps and now he's just sitting inside the trap in my animal stockpile.

I was thinking I'd memorialize him by putting him in a cage located in my tomb. So I built a cage (`b`->`j`), and I went to assign the dwarf to the cage. But his name is not listed in the assignments list.

How do I put him there?

Comment: You could try building the specific cage he is already in instead of moving him after.

Comment: @Nick I tried to build a 1x1 animal stockpile and then moving the trap on it, but the dwarves did not move the correct trap. I think they just pick at random?

Comment: For stockpiles they do indeed pick at something resembling random. However, I was talking about building the cage that already has the zombie in it. When you build a cage (or many other things) with b->j, the game will ask you which cage you want to build. The default form for this menu just lists cages by material, but if you hit either tab,'x' or 'z' (I don't recall which but it says in the menu) it will let you choose from the list of all the individual unbuilt cages you have. Then you should be able to go down the list and select the cage with the dwarf zombie in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the spot you want the cage: choose build, then cage. It should give you a list of all the cages in your fort by material.

hit 'x' and it'll then show you every single cage, and what they contain. Look for something like 'Dwarf wooden Cage'.

Choose to build this cage, and it should be placed and built in the spot you've chosen.